# How to calculate exchange rate with python script

Tags: python

A bank has the following exchange rates: 83.5 ($ to tzsh), 86.8 (tzsh to $). A customer wants to repeatedly exchange 1,000 dollars back and forth from dollars to shillings and vice versa. Develop a simple program (in any language) to show after how many exchanges the customer ends up with zero.

I am new at Python and I am sure there is something wrong with my code:

```
x=0
y=1000
while x<1000:
    x=(83.5*y)/86.8
    print x
    y=x
```

Comment: What is the *wrong* thing? The algorithm? Or the result?

Comment: both the algorithm and result do not give may any reasonable output

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your question a little, since it turned up in the "Help and Improvement" queue. However, since your question is a debugging question, it is lacking some important information. Can you tell us what you expect to happen and what actually happens? That would make your question a easier to understand and hence easier to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is it only approaches but never actually reaches 0. So, you might want to either set it less than 1 or check when it's really really close to 0 depending on your requirement.

```
balance = 1000
transactions = 0

while balance > 1:
    shillings = balance * 83.5
    balance = shillings / 86.8
    transactions += 1
print(transactions, balance)
```

Output:

```
179 0.9701710363275966
```

So on transaction number 179, the balance becomes less than $1.

If you want to count conversion from $ to shillings and back as two transactions, instead of `transactions += 1`, use `transactions += 2`

Comment: Thanks Ashish, that helps

Answer (score 3):

My answer is going to deviate from Ashish's answer because he considers the exchange from $ to tzsh and tzsh to $ as 1 transaction, while my approach considers $-to-tzsh and tzsh-to-$ as separate transactions:

```
i = 0
currency = 1000
while currency > 1:
    if i % 2 == 0:  # if converting from $ to tzsh
        currency = 83.5 * currency
    else:  # if converting from tzsh to $
        currency = currency / 86.8
    i += 1
print(i)
```

Result:

```
358
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you will stuck into endless while loop because the condition never fulfilled.Here, you need to change the condition to check whether $ is remaining to you or not.

```
x=0
y=1000
while y>0:
    x=(83.5*y)/86.8
    y=int(x)
    print x, y
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you not just post some code but also explain what you have changed and why.